# mysql: split varchar value and insert parts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a denormalised records in my table:

```
ID, CODES
1   |1|2|3|4
2   |5|6|7|8
```

In second column there are int values, saved in varchar field separated by | symbol.
I want to convert them to normal Many2Many relational form, using link table. 
So I want to create a table like this

```
ID CODE
1  1
1  2
1  3
1  4
....
2  8
```

I understand that I can iterate through the records in mysql stored function, split string and insert value. But I am interested: is it possible to convert data this way **without** stored procedure/function, but using only query (create table ... select ...)? 
Thanks.

UPD: There is variable number of codes in different rows. Each line has from 1 to 15 codes.

Comment: What is the maximum number of codes in one cell?

Comment: Are there only four "columns" in the code field or is it variable?  Your example only shows 4 "|" separated fields.

Comment: @biziclop There is variable number of codes in different rows. Each line has from 1 to 15 codes.

Comment: Are the codes single digit (0-9) or can they be >9?

Comment: @HolgerBrandt positive integers, now in range ~ 1-200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it works, inclusive test data and so on.

**But** consider that this is just a **fun** answer. The way to go is clearly a stored procedure or a function or whatever.

```
drop table testvar;
create table testvar (id int, codes varchar(20));
insert into testvar values (1, '|1|2|3|4'), (2, '|5|6|7|8');



drop table if exists inserttest;
create table inserttest (id int, code int);

select @sql:=left(concat('insert into inserttest values ', group_concat( '(', id, ',', replace(right(codes, length(codes) - 1), '|', concat( '),(', id, ',' )), '),' separator '')), length(concat('insert into inserttest values ', group_concat( '(', id, ',', replace(right(codes, length(codes) - 1), '|', concat( '),(', id, ',' )), '),' separator ''))) -1)
from testvar;

prepare stmt1 from @sql;
execute stmt1;

select * from inserttest;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle way is:

```
insert into newtestvar
select t.id, to_number(substr(t.codes, p1 + 1, p2))
from (
  select testvar.id, testvar.codes, s.num,
   instr(testvar.codes, '|',1,s.num) p1,
   instr(testvar.codes||'|', '|',1,s.num + 1)- instr(testvar.codes, '|',1,s.num) - 1 p2
  from testvar, (select level num from dual connect by level <= 15) s
  where s.num <= (length(testvar.codes)-length(replace(testvar.codes, '|')))
) t;
```

I hope you can adapt it for mysql.