# when i inserting the string in table at a same time that string split by comma and the sub strings are insert into another table(table 2)

Tags: mysql

I'm beginner to Mysql stored procedures.

I have `Table ONE`:

```
C1
100,23,45,677,77
```

`C1` is `varchar` type  column of `Table ONE`.

And I also have `Table TWO`

`C1` to `C5` is columns of `Table TWO` of `varchar` type.

I want to split C1 value of `Table ONE`, at the same time I have to insert into

`Table TWO` as `C1=100 , C2 = 23 …..C5 = 77`

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5

100 23  45  677 77
```

I'm stuck in Help me out of this problem Anybody
here we have to use only MYSQL stored procedure.

Comment: refer the following question it will help out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099493/mysql-split-varchar-value-and-insert-parts

Answer (score 1):

use **explode** function of php to make your comma seperated string as an array then insert array index 0-4 for table2 5 columns